# How to add a child to a specific node in n-array tree?

Tags: java, arrays, search, tree

I wrote this n-array tree class. I want to write a method to add a child to a specific node in my tree.

First I should search my tree to find the father then add the child to that node children.
I don't know how I should declare my method

```
public class FamilyNode {
    public String name;
    public String Family;
    public String sex;
    public FamilyNode Father;
    public FamilyNode Mother;
    public FamilyNode Spouse=null;
    public String status="alive";
    public int population;
    public ArrayList<FamilyNode> children=new ArrayList<FamilyNode>() ;


    public FamilyNode(String firstname,String lastname,String sex1){
        this.name=firstname;
        this.Family=lastname;
        this.sex=sex1;
        this.population=this.children.size()+1;
    }

    public void SetParents(FamilyNode father,FamilyNode mother){
        this.Father=father;
        this.Mother=mother;
    }

    public void SetHW(FamilyNode HW){
        this.Spouse=HW;
    }

    public int Number (){
        int number_of_descendants = this.population;

        if(this.Spouse!=null) number_of_descendants++;

        for(int index = 0; index < this.children.size(); index++)
            number_of_descendants = number_of_descendants+ this.children.get(index).Number();
            return number_of_descendants;
    }

    public void AddChild(FamilyNode Father,FamilyNode child){

        //the code here                                         
    }                                        
}
```

Comment: Please could you fix your indentation and whitespace; this is very hard to read right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered one of your [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275817/need-a-search-method-for-my-treen-ary-tree/11275928#11275928) yesterday so let's continue with the code I posted :)

```
public class FamilyNode {
    // ...
    // ...
    public FamilyNode findNodeByName(String nodeName){
       if(name.equals(nodeName)){
          // We found a node named nodeName, return it
          return this;
       } 
       // That's not me that you are looking for, let's see my kids
       for(FamilyNode child : children){
            if(child.findNodeByName(nodeName) != null) 
                // We found what we are looking, just return from here
                return child;
       }
       // Finished looping over all nodes and did not find any, return null
       return null;
    }

    public void addChild(FamilyNode child){
       children.add(child);
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to find the node you are looking for (by name in this case) and that can be done by the `findNodeByName` above. Once the node is found, add one child to it.

Use this code like this:

```
FamilyNode root = ...;
FamilyNode node = root.findNodeByName("Parent");
if(node != null) node.addChild(...);
```

**NOTE**
If you want to debug and visit all your tree nodes, use this method:

```
public FamilyNode findNodeByName(String nodeName){
   System.out.println("Visiting node "+ name);
   // That's not me that you are looking for, let's see my kids
   for(FamilyNode child : children){
     child.findNodeByName(nodeName)
   }
   // Finished looping over all nodes and did not find any, return null
   return null;
}
```

Comment: `for(FamilyNode child : node.children) whats node? 
`

Comment: Oops sorry, it should be just `children`. Please see my updates

Comment: you know whats my problem? i need return the whole root(tree) after adding one child , in this way we find a node and add a child to it but after that we dont have the first tree with added child i hope could say it correct

Comment: The root of your tree should not change, keep a reference to it all the time, that way you can access your whole tree whenever you want. I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: there is a problem ! :(  your method only works for root's children and cant find the children of children and return the father of them could you understand me ?

Comment: It works here. Please make sure your parent root's children are correctly linked to their children. This method will explore all related children reachable from the parent

Comment: i trace this method line by line evrything is ok but it returns the incorrect answer :(

Comment: Are you sure you don't have more then one node with the same name? Cuz the code above will stop at the first node that matches the name you are looking for

Comment: yeah i am sure that the names are diffrent

Comment: Mmm, Ok here is one trick. do a `rootNode.findNodeByName("");` and add a `System.out.println(node.name);` inside the `findNodeByName` it should print all nodes.

Comment: `public FamilyNode findNodeByName(String nodeName){
       if(true){
         
         System.out.println(this.name);
       } 
     
       for(FamilyNode child : children){
            if(child.findNodeByName(nodeName) != null) 
              
                System.out.println(child.name);
       }
     
       return null;
    } `it pritn the rootname 3 time

Comment: Please see my edit, I posted some code to help you out debug your tree

Comment: yeah my tree is correct i debug with your last code , it print all nodes but your first code always return the child of root for all children :) dont know whats wrong :(

Comment: Mmm May be you should ask another question and see if the community can help you out. I do not see anything wrong with the code :(

Comment: Sure no problem :) I wish I could have helped more

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a tree, as children have potentially two parents rather than just one.  It's a directed graph.

It would be good to change your variable and method names to be consistent with the usual Java convention of starting with a lowercase character.

In the interest of data consistency, you might consider making the `addChild` method something that simply adds to the list of children for the current node, but in your `setParents` method, update the child lists of both parents, adding the current node as a child there, by calling `father.addChild(this)` and `mother.addChild(this)` (protecting against them being null of course).

If the parents can be changed when they're previously set (presumably in error), you'll also need to remove the current node from previously set parents.  For this, you might need a `removeChild(FamilyNode child)` method.  Again for data consistency, this method should probably also set the appropriate parent field in the child node to null.